# headless designer and ODP .project file

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

we are testing a setup to automate building of NSF's using headless designer.

when a developer pushes a change to a repository on github ultimately this will result in an update of an NSF that resides on a Domino server.

local odp -> github -> local nsf with headless designer -> replace design nsf on domino server

however we noticed that the process stops sometimes. as far as we can see headless designer cannot "copy" (or translate) the design elements from the ODP into a new local NSF. so only an empty skeleton NSF is created.

we noticed that the stop does NOT occurs when the name property in the .project file of the ODP has changed.

so somehow it looks as designer still has the ODP in memory and does not notice any changes, unless it "finds" a "new" project via the project description "name".

anyone experienced something similar ? or recommendations how to start designer without any cache?

Answer (score 1):

An (in-?)elegant solution which I use, since I want to keep things tidy and separate for each build, is to **compute a unique filename for the NSF**. This will create a separate NSF for each build and while it will retain things like the Application name and template name, it is unique in enough other ways to not cause issues for the DDE headless build.

Defining in CI Config

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wyI.png)

Using Env Vars in PowerShell Script

[image]

For example, I use an app specific prefix, defined in my GitLab CI config, which then is used with the unique build number (both set as environment variables), which my modified version of [Egor Margineanu's PowerShell script](https://www.egmar.ro/blog/2014/02/10/using-continous-integration-in-xpages-projects/) picks up for the build.

#### Bottom Line

The unique namespacing means no conflict from DDE's perspective.

Comment: i did the same to get around this problem. it's also worth mentioning to set the DDE source control preferences so it only imports and no export.  i now have an different approach which I use my own designer plugin to run designer like a 'server' that stays on and just refresh/builds existing nsfs instead of launching, import and create a new one every time. it also allows to check success / failure and get a summary of build errors. i should blog about it really

Comment: the filename of the nsf has an incremental part so should be unique at every attempt. as mentioned we do however notice a difference when we change the name of the project in the ODP project file.

Comment: may I know which settings you have set for DDE ?

Comment: I believe you should check two things, 1- that your "Enable automatic export of the design elements (from NSF to disk) on modification" is un-checked (Preferences > Domino Designer > Source Control), since that never hurts, and 2- that you don't have any other ODPs with the same application or ODP name in your Project Explorer for the DDE you're using. My understanding is that my "one-off" imports via my CI config don't permanently add the ODP to DDE, meaning I can re-use one with the same name again later without issue.

Comment: I assume you mean "Package Explorer" in stead of Project Explorer?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.